# bulk write in an Oracle database with OCCI c++

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

I am new to oracle database with occi.

I want to know how can i insert multiple row at single time with occi in my c++ code?

```
int createStatement(Connection* i_pDBConn)
    {
        int retVal = SUCCESS;

        try
        {
            m_pDBStmt = i_pDBConn->createStatement("INSERT INTO RATED_EVENT_EPM VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5)");
        }
        catch(SQLException& ex)
        {
            cout<<__FILE__<<":"<<__LINE__<<" "<<ex.getMessage()<<endl;
            retVal = FAILURE;
            return retVal;
        }

        m_pDBStmt->setMaxIterations(1000);
        m_pDBStmt->setMaxParamSize(1, 10);

        return retVal;
    }


    int insertRatedEventDetailInDB(Connection* i_pDBConn, string i_string)
    {
        int retVal = SUCCESS;

        try
        {
            m_pDBStmt->setString(1, i_string);

            if((0 != m_pDBStmt->getCurrentIteration()) && 0 == (m_pDBStmt->getCurrentIteration()%1000))
            {
                m_pDBStmt->executeUpdate();
                i_pDBConn->commit();
            }
            else
            {
                m_pDBStmt->addIteration();
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException& ex)
        {
            cout<<__FILE__<<":"<<__LINE__<<" "<<ex.getMessage()<<endl;
            retVal = FAILURE;
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

so after created statement single time and then call "insertRatedEventDetailInDB" function multiple time to multiple insert row and need to execute after every 1000 time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for executeArrayUpdate():

> If all data is provided with the setDataBuffer() methods or output
> streams (that is, no setxxx() methods besides setDataBuffer() or
> getStream() are called), then there is a simplified way of doing
> iterative execution.
>
> In this case, you should not call setMaxIterations() and
> setMaxParamSize(). Instead, call the setDataBuffer() or getStream()
> method for each parameter with the appropriate size arrays to provide
> data for each iteration, followed by the executeArrayUpdate(int
> arrayLength) method. The arrayLength parameter specifies the number of
> elements provided in each buffer. Essentially, this is same as setting
> the number of iterations to arrayLength and executing the statement.

See Oracle's documentation for more details - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/appdev.11203/e10764/performance.htm